# Wrap widget inside text in flutter

Tags: flutter

How to wrap a widget inside a multiline text in flutter.

[image: Container inside text]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this with [RichText](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/RichText-class.html) and [WidgetSpan](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/WidgetSpan-class.html).
Example from [this link](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/WidgetSpan-class.html):

```
const Text.rich(
  TextSpan(
    children: <InlineSpan>[
      TextSpan(text: 'Flutter is'),
      WidgetSpan(
        child: SizedBox(
          width: 120,
          height: 50,
          child: Card(
            child: Center(
              child: Text('Hello World!')
            )
          ),
        )
      ),
      TextSpan(text: 'the best!'),
    ],
  )
)
```